# Can we send a JavaScript variable through the anchor tag in jsp

Tags: javascript, xml, jsp, anchor

I need to pass the userid variable from one page to another page through anchor tag `<a>`. This user id will be display in every pages after sign in. Here I attached code for that

Code:

```
<td colspan="2" align="right"><div align="center">User Id</div></td>
<td><input class="textbox" type="text" id="userid" ><a href="access.jsp?userid='+userid'" 
"></a></td></tr>
 Javascript:
       var  userid =document.getElementBy("userid");
```

Comment: That's not a Java variable. That's a JavaScript variable. Please get them straight and don't mix them, they are fundamentally completely different languages. As to the concrete question, is there any reason why you don't just use a form and a submit button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to manipulate the `href` attribute with javascript in order to insert the value. You could achieve this, for instance, by using an `onclick` event handler:

```
<a href="access.jsp" onclick="appendUserId(this)">

<script>
function appendUserId(e){
    e.href = e.href + "?userid=" + document.getElementById('userId').value;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The most basic way would be setting JavaScript `window.location` to that URL.

```
<input class="textbox" type="text" id="userid" />
<a href="javascript:window.location='access.jsp?userid=' + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementBy('userid'))">link</a>
```

or

```
<input class="textbox" type="text" id="userid" />
<a href="#" onclick="window.location='access.jsp?userid=' + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementBy('userid'))">link</a>
```

However, the normal way is to just use a form for that, this way the parameter ends up "automagically" in the URL without the need for a nasty JS based hack/workaround:

```
<form action="access.jsp">
    <input class="textbox" type="text" name="userid" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

If your major concern is the styling of the button, just throw in some CSS to make it look like a link.

Please note that this all is completely unrelated to JSP as it's just a HTML/CSS/JS code producer. You'd have had exactly the same problem in other server side view technologies which also produces HTML/CSS/JS, such as PHP, ASP, etc.

Comment: Is encoding of URL required (using some function(s) of JavaScript), in this scenario? I just wanted to know - unrelated to the concrete question.